# mysql tuning variables - current & defaults

Tags: mysql, performance, database-performance

I have a pretty vanilla mysql 5.1 setup, and I am trying to tune it. I found this [handy script](https://github.com/rackerhacker/MySQLTuner-perl)

It made the following suggestions:

```
query_cache_limit (> 1M, or use smaller result sets)
query_cache_size (> 16M)
join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
table_cache (> 64)
innodb_buffer_pool_size (>= 14G)
```

In reading up on what these mean and what they are currently set to, I found that I can run "mysqladmin variables"

My current values are:

```
query_cache_limit                       | 1048576  
query_cache_size                        | 16777216   
join_buffer_size                        | 131072     
innodb_buffer_pool_size                 | 8388608
```

How do I read these, are they Kbytes? so is that 1M, 16M, 13M and 8M?

My box is only 4G of Ram and on a normal day only had a few hundred megs free of memory. Should I follow these suggestions and do:

```
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 15G
#table_cache = 128
#join_buffer_size = 32M
#query_cache_size = 64M
#query_cache_limit = 2M
```

Im confused by the 15G, is this a disk space thing, not a memory thing? If so then the recommendations are not very good right?

Should I get more memory for my box?

More Info:
- My db size is 34Gigs, I use all innodb, I have 71 tables, 4 of them are huge, the rest are small. Ive been thinking of moving the big ones to SOLR and doing all queries from there, but wanted to see what I can do with basic tuning.

thanks
Joel

Comment: I found this a useful read http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/11/03/choosing-innodb_buffer_pool_size/

Comment: This might be better asked on serverfault.com

Comment: I read the perfblog, but was still confused, I think it assumes you already know what that variable is and does.

Comment: Regarding `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, if you are using InnoDB for your tables, this is generally the biggest factor in performance.  You want to make it as big as you possibly can.  If you are using MyISAM though, it makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: I am all innodb, thanks.

Comment: Actually 
innodb_buffer_pool_size                 | 8388608  
is 8M, not 83M

Comment: Do you have anything other running on the server, or it's only MySQL? I'm asking because of the "only few hundreds MB available"

Comment: Yes, other stuff is running, this is a rails app/apache/passenger/mysql, lots of batch jobs running at night gathering and crunching data, web front end is pretty low usage. Eventually plan to break up the arch, but for now all on one vm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not set your innodb buffer pool higher than your available memory. The script probably recommended that based on the number of records in your table and their physical size. Innodb performance is very much memory based, if it can fit the indexes in memory, performance is going to drop quickly and noticeably. So setting innodb_buffer_pool_size high is almost always good advice.

Innodb is not the best table type for everything when it comes to mysql. Very large tables that generally have a lot of inserts, but few reads and updates (i.e. logging) are better off as MyISAM tables. Your very active tables (inserts, updates, deletes, selects) are better off Innodb. There may be a flame war on this advice, and it is generic advice.

But that said, no script is going to being to tell you what your settings should be. It can only make a best guest. The best settings are based on your data access patterns. You really have to read up on what all the variables are. mysqlperformanceblog.com is an excellent place for learning about mysql, in addition to the manual.

When in mysql, use "show variables" and "show status" to see what's going on. You can also run "show innodb status", but you may not understand that output if you don't know what the variables are.

Comment: Thanks, this seems like some good advice, I upgraded my vm and added more memory, running I had about 8 gigs free, so I set the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 4G. When I started mysql I expected it to use up this 4G memory, but I dont see it. Right now after running a big batch job all night its using 68m resident and 331m swap. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I read your "show variables" and tried that, and mysql is still showing the old number for innodb_buffer_pool_size... not sure what I did wrong, I added the vars to my.cnf and restarted mysql..

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, duh I put the variables in the wrong section of the my.cnf, thanks for the idea to check the show variables.

Comment: When you run "show innodb status", the is a section "buffer pool and memory" that will be helpful in telling what is being used.

Comment: Here is what is says so far: ----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 4748342496; in additional pool allocated 1048576
Dictionary memory allocated 388080
Buffer pool size   262144
Free buffers       47623
Database pages     202766
Modified db pages  1
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages read 202766, created 0, written 680
10.82 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.09 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 999 / 1000